# Only display sticky post or latest post in custom loop

Tags: posts, loop, sticky-post

I'm new to Wordpress and PHP and I've been battling with this for a while now. What I have for the moment is 2 loops.

I want to first loop to only ever show 1 post: either a sticky post, or the latest post if there are no sticky posts.

The second loop should show all other recent posts, like a basic blog, except any posts which are stickied or the recent post which appears in the first loop.

**Example:**
[image]

**What I have:**

My code shows the latest post in the first loop and other posts in the second loop.

**The problem:**

When I make a sticky post, it appears in the first loop along with the latest post (I only want the sticky post to appear here in this situation and not both), and it also appears at the top of the second loop.

[Here](http://bit.ly/1qS0MMC) it is in action

I've managed to get this far but I can't seem to finish it.

**UPDATED**

```
<div id="main" class="site-main">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
            <div>
            <?php 

            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                'post__in'  => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
            );
            $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

            $do_not_duplicate = array();
            while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
            $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( '' ); ?> >
        <div class="featuredimage">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('home-thumbnail'); ?></a>
        </div>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); //VERY VERY IMPORTANT?>
            </div>
<div id="gridcontainer">
<?php
$counter = 1; //start counter

$grids = 2; //Grids per row

global $query_string; //Need this to make pagination work

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
if ( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>
<?php
//Show the left hand side column
if($counter == 1) :
?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'griditemleft' ); ?> >
            <div class="postimage">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('home-thumbnail'); ?></a>
            </div>
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        </div>
<?php
//Show the right hand side column
elseif($counter == $grids) :
?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'griditemright' ); ?>>
            <div class="postimage">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('home-thumbnail'); ?></a>
            </div>
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
<?php
    $counter = 0;
    endif;
?>
<?php
    $counter++;
    endwhile;
    //Pagination can go here if you want it.
    endif;
?>
<?php
    untitled_content_nav( 'nav-below' );
?>
</div>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
```

**IN FUNCTIONS.PHP**

```
/*===================================================================================
* Homepage sticky filter in loop 2
* =================================================================================*/
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpse161279_ignore_sticky_posts');
// the function that does the work
function wpse161279_ignore_sticky_posts($query)
{
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
        $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( $sticky[0] ) );
    }   
}
```

Comment: I'd really appreciate some help

Comment: You are not very clear. Do you need to display the sticky in loop one or two

Comment: Hi Pieter,

In loop 1 : Just the latest sticky OR the latest post.
In loop 2 : All other latest posts and stickies (basically everything that's not in loop 1).

Answer (score 2):

You can adapt your first loop to either show a sticky post or the latest post in the following manner: *PLEASE NOTE: You have to reset your custom query*

```
<?php 

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post__in'  => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

$do_not_duplicate = array();
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
    $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( '' ); ?> >
            <div class="featuredimage">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('home-thumbnail'); ?></a>
            </div>
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); //VERY VERY IMPORTANT?>
```

Source: [Sticky Posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts)

**EDIT**

The remove sticky posts from the main query, you can make use of the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action to remove sticky posts before the main query executes. Paste the following in your functions.php

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpse161279_ignore_sticky_posts');
// the function that does the work
function wpse161279_ignore_sticky_posts($query)
{
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query())
        $query->set('post__not_in', get_option('sticky_posts'));
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I haven't tested this, nor am I familiar with this, but I think you can try to do the following

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpse161279_ignore_sticky_posts');
// the function that does the work
function wpse161279_ignore_sticky_posts($query)
{
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
        $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( $sticky[0] ) );
    }   
}
```

**EDIT 3**

Paste the following code just after line 4 in your first block of code in your question and then post the results

```
<pre><?php var_dump($wp_query->query_vars['post__not_in']); ?></pre>    
<pre><?php var_dump(get_option( 'sticky_posts' )); ?></pre>
<pre><?php var_dump($wp_query->query_vars['ignore_sticky_posts']); ?></pre>
```

You should get results familiar than these

[image]

**EDIT 4**

Add the following to the code above. This will print the ID of the first post. If it matches the second value of the second result, it means that your sticky post is actually displayed like it should

```
<pre><?php var_dump($wp_query->posts[0]->ID); ?></pre>
```

**EDIT 5**

FYI, this is how your site looks on my side. I have just removed the text parts and kept the images

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work. I've updated my question with all the code I currently have.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work. You will need to explain

Comment: The sticky shown in loop 1 is also shown at the top of loop 2, and the other stickies which aren't shown in loop 1 don't show in loop 2.

Comment: This is strange, it works perfectly on my site. You did not by change also use the code in edit 1.

Comment: I checked and I didn't use the code in edit 1 anywhere. If you want me to let you into the wp-admin I don't mind, email me: patrick@pixxi.es.

Comment: I don't want to scratch around on someone's site, unfortunately. I can't think of anything now that might influence this. Clear all your caches, as well plugin caches if you are using cache plugins. Also test on a bundled theme

Comment: Aha! Clearing the cache made it work better! Just one thing missing: the stickies which aren't shown in loop 1 still aren't showing as normal posts in loop 2.

Comment: Please see my update and comment and post results

Comment: `array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(10)
}` `array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(10)
  [1]=>
  int(6)
}` `bool(false)`

Comment: OK, you must have a sticky post showing somewhere. The post ID is `6`, As you can see, only post ID 10 is removed and you have two stickies, ID 6 and 10.

Comment: Paste the following on the same place as before and post result `<pre><?php var_dump($wp_query->posts[0]->ID); ?></pre>`

Comment: Shows: `int(6)`

Comment: Problem solved. Your first post that is displayed in your second loop **is** your second sticky post. I think you forgot which post you assigned as a sticky post. Open your website with a different browser. Please accept my answer by clicking on the check mark next to my answer. Thank you :-)

Comment: See my last update

Comment: Yes, but the second sticky is shown nowhere on my site.

Comment: Post 10 is missing, post 6 is showing in place of post 10. Post 10 is either not published, or it is somehow being removed with some other code, or some cache is showing this weird behavior or something funny is happening. Your code and my code is working perfectly on my side. Don't you have any other custom queries on your page that might influence and create this behavior. It has to be something else, because it is **not** my code, neither the code you've posted

Comment: One last thing, set debug to true in wp-config.php.

Comment: Ok I turned it on. Is there anything I should look for?

Comment: Yes, any error messages, warnings, notices.

Comment: "bp_setup_current_user was called incorrectly" and "wp_deregister_script was called incorrectly". Both in functions.php

Comment: I would start by first clearing these errors. Apart from that, you will need to dig into your theme to see what is happening. I'm of to bed now. Hope you solve this.

Comment: My sticky posts can now only be opened when logged in (otherwise 404 error), even when the errors shown with wp_debug are cleared it still doesn't seem to show post ID 10, and on page 2 of posts the <pre> code is still showing even though I deleted it :/

Answer (score 2):

There's a much simpler way and lighter way.
By definition sticky posts will come first on the loop.
So on your featured area (before any call to the_post() ) you can put:

```
<div>
   <h3>Special Featured Loop</h3>
   <?php the_post(); //this will get the first post, and generate all the tags the_title(), the_permalink(),... ?>  
   <h2 class="entry-title">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
   </h2>
</div>
```

Don't need to reset because you want to ignore the previous article.
To ignore sticky post you can use the is_sticky() function.
On your main loop you can put this:

```
<div>
    <h3>Loop ignoring the sticky posts</h3>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php if(is_sticky()) continue; //ignore sticy posts?>
        <h2 class="entry-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h2>
    <?php endwhile; // End the loop. Whew. ?>       
</div>
```

Hope that this helps you.

Cheers